# nvm (node version manager) nvm,node,npm not found

Tags: macos, symlink, zsh

I did install nvm regarding the [documentation](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating), then installed the latest LTS node, `nvm install 12.16.1` and globally installed yarn.

everything was working well, the `node -v` and `npm -v` and `which node` were showing what they should.

I did create a react-native app and the metro bundler had a problem finding node. The solution was to make a symlink(`ln -s $(which node) /usr/local/bin/node`).

Since then, `nvm`, `npm`, `yarn` commands are not found by the terminal (zsh).

I could not find a proper way to install node via nvm where all programs and shells can have access to it. Without needing symbolic links or so.

This is the script added to `.bash_profile` after installing nvm

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm

[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```